# ASP.NET Looking to disable Button on click event

Tags: asp.net

Hey looking for method to disable button after clicked, but I guess only after it passes validation because need to enter a second time.

EDIT :

Looking for a disable function which does the following
1) Disables the button onclick
2) when a user hits the back button in the browser the button is no longer disabled

Currently have

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProceedStepTwo" runat="server" Text="Proceed &nbsp;&rarr;" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnProceedTwo_Click" />
```

and in code behind

```
btnProceedStepTwo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + GetPostBackEventReference(btnProceedStepTwo).ToString());
```

Comment: You are *guessing* what your requirements are?

Comment: Hey..how about taking some time to explaing the question a little better with some sample code you have used so that people who can answer need not start with 100% guessed code?

Comment: Am i understanding you correctly, you want to disable the button when all validators are valid from codebehind and not because you want to prevent the user from double-click the button at short interval? Why not setting `btnProceedStepTwo.Enabled = False` from codebhind after the validation?

Comment: Hey sorry scratch that about validation. I just noticed it works fine regardless. What I am looking for is that when a user submits the button, it disables and loads next page. This works and is fine. But when a user hits the back button in the browser (because this is a multi step form) the button is still disabled. How do I renable it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable submit button before page postback. Here is a link describing use of javascript to do so:  
[Disable Button before Page PostBack in ASP.Net](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Button-before-Page-PostBack-in-ASP.Net.aspx)